# Highcharts bubble graph bubble getting cut off on top

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts bubble graph on my page and the top of one of the bubbles is getting chopped off because it is right at the top of the y axis. I've set the maxSize to 50% and would like to keep it that way. Is there a way to allow the bubbles to not have this overflow hidden sort of effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an example I can only say to try adjusting the yAxis max value. That way there would be space to render your items. Or you can calculate your highest yValue bubble's radius and increase your yAxis by that pixel ammount in yAxis values.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about as well. I was hoping there would have been a built-in way to fix this with a property, but this solves my problem.

Comment: I haven't seen a way to accomplish this with any of the existing properties. I've just done this for now. Thanks!